# How important is WCAG and Why I am getting this error?

Tags: accessibility, dreamweaver, wcag

I am analysing my site in dreamweaver and I got this error

**object should have device indepedent interface and it says something like wcag 9.2**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="ibtnSearch_Click" ImageUrl="images/img_search.jpg" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" align="left" />
```

help needed

I just run analyzing in dreamweaver and it gave me these results. I am working in dreamweaver 8

Comment: How are you analyzing your site (what options are you selecting if in Dreamweaver, or what web site are you using to analyzing your page/site), and what is the specific message that you are getting (as "something like wcag 9.2" is hardly useful in trying to figure out what you're running into?

Also, are you running this on the generated page (through the web browser), or on the ASP.NET code itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely getting this error because of the OnClick="ibtnSearch_Click"

This is because the onclick event handler is a device dependant solution; it allows access via mouse clicks, but not strictly speaking keypresses (like Enter for instance). This is generally a moot point as modern browsers will send an onclick event when a keyboard user accesses an interface element anyway.

To determine if you can safely ignore this error: try navigating your page using just the keyboard. Use Tab to select the image button in question, and then press Enter to activate it. Does this work? if so, you can ignore this error.

Note: People who may not make use of the mouse include users with RSI, or blind users who cannot see the cursor and so rely on keyboard access facilitated by screenreading software.